# How to copy the data from file to array in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am pasting code ..which I am able to read file and but not able to put into array there is runtime error I am getting.I have made line bold where i am getting error.Anyone help me out I am quite new to VB.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog

            ' Set filter options and filter index.
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1

    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

            ' Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialogbox.
    Dim UserClickedOK As Boolean = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName)

        ' Dim hexval As String
          '  Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter
     Dim buff(data.Length()) As String
     Dim counter As Integer
     Dim Arr() As String = Nothing

        ' the file path and the file name to the StreamWriter constructor.
        ' objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\users \karmic\My Documents\Text.txt")

            'Write a line of text.
     For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
     **Arr(i) = Hex(data(i))**                       -runtime error

      If i = data.Length() - 1 Then

      Continue For
      End If
      If (Hex(data(i))) = (Hex(data(i + 1))) Then
      counter = counter + 1
      ' MsgBox(counter)
      Continue For
      Else
                'objStreamWriter.Write(hexval)
                'MsgBox(hexval)

                ' Array.Copy(hexval, Arr(i), data.Length)
                'objStreamWriter.Write(", ")
                'objStreamWriter.Write(Hex(counter + 1))
      MsgBox(Hex(counter + 1))
                'objStreamWriter.Write(", ")


     End If
              'MsgBox(Array.Length())
     Next
     End Sub
     End Class
```

Comment: What does your error say? And BTW, no lines are bold. Use 2 asterisks ("*") before and after the code you want to make bold.

Comment: I am getting runtime error as NullReference exception was unhandheld.To make line bold I have 2 * before and after to make that line bold.

Comment: You're trying to set one of the array values when the array (Arr) itself is set to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Arr()` seemed to be a dynamic array because you did not include the upper bound of the array when declaring it. You need to re-declare a dynamic array every time you want to change the upper bound of the array by using `ReDim` statement.

```
ReDim Preserve Arr(i) = Hex(data(i))
```

Every time you use `ReDim`, your values in all the dynamic array elements will be deleted. Hence, in this case, you have to specify `Preserve` statement every time you re-declare the array to preserve the values of the elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Dev I added Redim preserve getting an error saying end of statement expected.

Comment: yeah its working out but need to declare as ReDim preserve Arr(i)      first and then use it.